# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in your code on line 47

Tags: php, post, global-variables

Here's the code:

> Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in your code on line 47.

The line 47 is:

```
public function add_status($user_id, $_POST)
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require_once('class-db.php');
if ( !class_exists('INSERT') ) {
    class INSERT
        {
            public function update_user($user_id, $postdata)
                {
                    global $db;
                    $table = 's_users';

                    $query = "
                            UPDATE $table
                            SET user_email='$postdata[user_email]', user_pass='$postdata[user_pass]', user_nicename='$postdata[user_nicename]'
                            WHERE ID=$user_id
                        ";
                    return $db->update($query);
                }

            public function add_friend($user_id, $friend_id)
                {
                    global $db;
                    $table = 's_friends';
                    $query = "
                            INSERT INTO $table (user_id, friend_id)
                            VALUES ('$user_id', '$friend_id')
                        ";

                    return $db->insert($query);
                }

$insert = new INSERT;
?>
```

Any insights? Thanks :)

Comment: You connat send post array to function because post is available every where.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what @Nasir has said, `$_POST` is a super global so you can't declare it like that. You would just declare a regular variable and pass `$_POST`

```
public function add_status($user_id, $array)
    {
        // This will print whatever array you pass
        print_r($array);
    }
```

So to use:

```
$insert = new INSERT();
$insert->add_status(123, $_POST);
```

---

**Few side notes:**

> You would help yourself to inject your database instead of using `global $db;`:

```
class Insert
    {
        private $db;
        public function __construct($db)
            {
                $this->db = $db;
            }

        public function update_user($user_id, $postdata)
            {
                $table = 's_users';

                $query = "
                        UPDATE $table
                        SET user_email='$postdata[user_email]', user_pass='$postdata[user_pass]', user_nicename='$postdata[user_nicename]'
                        WHERE ID=$user_id
                    ";
                return $this->db->query($query);
            }

    }
// Insert the $db into the class
$insert = new Insert($db);
```

> Don't do variables into the sql. Use bind parameters:

```
// Use ? here
$sql =   "UPDATE `s_friends`
          SET `user_email` = ?, `user_pass` = ?, `user_nicename` = ?
          WHERE `ID` = ?";
// I am using PDO (if you use mysqli, look at bind param for that interface)
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($postdata['user_email'],$postdata['user_pass'],$postdata['user_nicename'],$user_id));
```

> Don't use plaintext passwords. You should be using a hash instead:

```
// Hash the password, then store that instead
$password = password_hash($postdata['user_pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// Use password_verify() to match the password
```

> Use class autoloading

Instead of using `if ( !class_exists('INSERT') ) {`, look into using a class autoloading with `spl_autoload_register()`